# SoapFault over https: Could not connect to host

Tags: openssl, pem, ota

I want to using SITA Web Services (SWS) with PHP soap . (CentOS 6 + PHP 5.6.9)
SWS is platform independent and is based on the OpenTravel Alliance (OTA) XML standards.

First I must generate a SSL DER file and send to them because:

> All connections and communications with SITA Web Services should be established using SSL on HTTPS port 443. Client applications will access the web services using SOAP over HTTPS.
>
> WS-Security describes enhancements to SOAP messaging to provide quality of protection through message integrity, message confidentiality, and single message authentication. These mechanisms can be used to accommodate a wide variety of security models and encryption technologies.
>
> To access SITA Web To access SITA Web Services, clients are required to create a key-pair PKI certificate, provide us with the public DER key and sign the message with the private PEM key. The certificate can be from a Certificate Authority (CA) or a self signed certificate but needs to adhere to X.509 version 3 standard.

I generated DER file with these commands like as they say:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -key key.pem -out cert.der -days 365 -outform DER
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out cert.csr -outform DER
```

Now when I want to sign in SITA web service, I get this error:

[xdebug_message] => ( ! ) SoapFault: Could not connect to host.

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled',0);
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl',0);
$pem = 'wsdl/cert.pem';
$defaultEndpoint = "https://sws.qa.sita.aero/sws/SignIn";
$uri = "https://sws.qa.sita.aerosws/sws";
$wsdl = 'wsdl/SITAReservationService.wsdl';
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <SITA_SignIn Version="0" Version="1" xmlns=http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05 xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xsi:schemaLocation="wsdl/SITA_PingRQ.xsd" TransactionIdentifier="">
        <POS>
            <Source AirlineVendorID="xx" ERSP_UserID="xx/xx" AgentSine="xx/xx" PseudoCityCode="xxxx" AgentDutyCode="xx" ISOCountry="xx" AirportCode="IKA" />
        </POS>
    </SITA_SignIn>';
try{
    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
            'location' => $defaultEndpoint,
            'uri' => $uri,
            'trace'             => 1,
            'exceptions'        => true,
            'connection_timeout'=> 30,
            'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true,
                    'cafile'        => $pem,
                    'CN_match'      => 'https://sws.qa.sita.aero',
                    'ciphers'             => 'ALL'
            )
    ));
    var_dump($client->SignIn($xml));
 }   
 catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    var_dump($fault);
}
```

How can I connect to SITA web service?

Comment: Hello,I am new in SITA webservices can you please help me how can I sue the SITA web services in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code:

1. Your URI is incorrect and should be "https://sws.sita.aero/sws".
2. Your request is wrong and should be `SITA_SignInRQ`.

But I think you'll still get a "No signature in message!" error from SITA.

Comment: Can you please help me how to start using SITA with PHP?